How to set up a log monitor in Datadog to alert on a specific error message within extendedStackTrace?
I'm currently working on setting up log monitoring in Datadog, and I'm trying to create a log monitor that alerts me whenever a specific error message occurs within the extendedStackTrace field of my logs. Specifically, I want to receive alerts when the message status: 407 Proxy Authentication Required is detected within the extendedStackTrace.
Here's a breakdown of what I'm aiming to achieve:
Log Scenario:
extendedStackTrace
io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpProxyConnectException: 
http, basic, <URL PATH WITH PROXY SERVICE>m/<unresolved>:443, status: 407 Proxy Authentication Required


My logs contain entries with extendedStackTrace, which includes detailed information about exceptions or errors that occurred in my application.

Target Error Message: I'm interested in detecting the occurrence of the error message status: 407 Proxy Authentication Required within the extendedStackTrace.

Alerting Requirement: I need to configure a log monitor in Datadog that triggers an alert whenever the specified error message is found in the extendedStackTrace field of any log entry.


Here's what I've tried so far:

I've explored the Log Analytics feature in Datadog but haven't been able to figure out how to specifically target the error message within the extendedStackTrace field.

I've attempted to create log queries using the "source" field to filter logs from the relevant source, but I'm unsure how to precisely match the error message within the extendedStackTrace.

Could someone provide guidance on how to set up a log monitor in Datadog to achieve this specific alerting requirement? Any insights, tips, or examples would be greatly appreciated!


